# CSS: slide to anchor after 1 scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress website and I want the following: when the user lands on the homepage and scrolls down I want the website to slide to the next section. This has to work immediatly when the user touches its mouse scroller and only then. I am able to slide to certain anchorpoints but how can I achieve this after the user only touches his mouse scroll 1 time?

This is not a duplicate of the submitted question. I want the page to scroll to a certain div or section after the user only touches his mouse scroll once. No clicking

Comment: Are you looking for this ?

http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

Comment: Yeah something like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag, and listen to a scroll event. When the scroll event triggers check if the flag is off, flip the flag if it is and then to what you need to do. If the flag is already flipped don't do anything. Easy :D

Comment: Care to provide an example of this?